# Not able to write SequenceFile in Scala for Array[NullWritable, ByteWritable]

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

I have a Byte Array in Scala: `val nums = Array[Byte](1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)` or you can take any other Byte array.

I want to save it as a sequence file in HDFS. Below is the code, I am writing in scala console.

```
import org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec
nums.map( x => (NullWritable.get(), new ByteWritable(x)))).saveAsSequenceFile("/yourPath", classOf[GzipCodec])
```

But, it's giving following error:

```
error: values saveAsSequenceFile is not a member of Array[ (org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable), (org.apache.hadoop.io.ByteWritable)]
```

You require to import these classes as well (in scala console).

```
import org.apache.hadoop.io.NullWritable
import org.apache.hadoop.io.ByteWritable
```

Comment: You're confusing Scala builtin `map()` with Spark's

Comment: I have seen above approach many time. that's why i went for it. But now I got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method saveAsSequenceFile is available on an RDD not on an array. So first you need to lift your array into an RDD and then you will be able to call the method saveAsSequenceFile

```
val v = sc.parallelize(Array(("owl",3), ("gnu",4), ("dog",1), ("cat",2), ("ant",5)), 2)
v.saveAsSequenceFile("hd_seq_file")
```

http://homepage.cs.latrobe.edu.au/zhe/ZhenHeSparkRDDAPIExamples.html

Comment: Great ! It works. Even other examples in that link are excellent. Thanks for sharing.